hdrcam_updater_v12の書き込みが失敗します。
下記ページに従ってアップデートしようとしましたが、失敗します。
https://developerworld.wpp.developer.sony.com/ja/spresense/downloads/fpga-updater/hdr-camera-fpga-updater-manual

spresenseのbootloaderは最新のver3.2.0にアップデートしてあります。
原因は何でしょうか？
宜しくお願い致します。

こんにちは。
私の方でも同じ現象になりましたが、
その後同じUpdaterを実行すると正しくアップデートできていました。
マニュアルにある、
「FPGAの書き込みが無事に完了すると、LED0～LED3が全て点灯した状態」
になっていました。
また、Updater spkを書き込んだ後、
Teratermなどでシリアルにつないでみると、
It has been updated already
と表示されています。
まずはこちらを確認してみると良いかもしれません。
